# Запуск Python-скрипта на веб-сервере

Tags: python, debian

Пытаюсь запустить python на веб-сервере. ОС: Debian 9.5

В папке со скриптом создал .htaccess

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py 
Options +ExecCGI
```

Создал файл test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print('Hello, world!')
```

Запускаю http://my-site.ru/test.py - 503 ошибка.
Что я упустил?

Comment: Права на скрипт выставили? Есть у него разрешение на выполнение?

Comment: Да, перепроверил, права 755.

Comment: @Геннадий что происходит, если запускаете из командной строки .\test.py ?

Comment: В командной строке запускаю
python test.py
Выдаёт Hello, world!

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80 , ну и, при повторении неудачи, логи программы apache смотрите.

Comment: В логах ошибка Permission denied:  AH01257: unable to connect to cgi daemon after multiple tries

Comment: @Геннадий python test.py и .\test.py - это два разных вида запуска, python test.py воспримет #!/usr/bin/python просто как комментарий, когда .\test.py  будет искать /usr/bin/python, как при запросе CGI